# using dotpeek exe I can convert my exe into sourcecode how to make secure my application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on Financial domain project using Windows application, Recently came to know that using **"DOTPEEKPACK exe"** I can get source code using my application exe. So there is no security for my code. It got some sensitive data too. 
even I try to convert my sensitive data code in to dll format but still using that dotpeek exe we can change dll to C# code.

kindly any one suggest me what to do for securing my windows application?

Comment: That's an odd nick-name, "Strong Text Sridhar"..

Comment: sorry @Blorgbeard wrong text its just Sridhar.

Comment: I know, just a joke :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use code obfuscation tools like Babel Obfuscator, Crypto obfuscator, dotfuscator by microsoft. it will modify your compiled assemblies in a way that it will be harder to understand the control flow of your code. different obfuscators use different types of obfuscation techniques like method and variable renaming, control flow obfuscation etc.

Comment: Reverse engineers make light work of most obfuscators. There are even tools that can virtually one-click reverse the effects of popular obfuscators.

Comment: @ByteBlast about Software "that which is runnable, is crackable" ;) You can only prolong the time to crack it... and can i know those "one click reverse" tools..? :)